# Convert SQL to LINQ query to get max

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

hi guys i am stuck converting below sql to LINQ query.
all i want is to have maximum number from list of  (FA-00001 ,FA-00059)

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ReferenceId, PATINDEX('%-%', ReferenceId) + 1, LEN(ReferenceId) - PATINDEX('%-%', ReferenceId)) AS int)) AS MaxReferenceId FROM [ClientRC].[dbo].[EHO_Action]
```

is this possible to convert to LINQ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach using anonymous projection:

```
var y = (from record in
                (from record in db.ClientRC
                select new
                {
                    Group = "x",
                    ReferenceNumber = Convert.ToInt32(record.ReferenceId.Split('-')[1])
                })
            group record by new { record.Group } into g
            select new
            {
                MaxReferenceId = g.Max(p => p.ReferenceNumber)
            });
```

Comment: whoaaa high level but i think it is not good performance wise? i can see inner query...:)

Comment: This is probably the case - I haven't tested. I just wanted to give you a readable, higher level example as a comparable.

Comment: thanks by the way...i am new in this LINQ world so it is nice to know more.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386972.aspx

```
var myvar = (from v in db.object where v!=null select v.id).Max();
```

MSDN has lots of examples for stuff like this.

Or, you can execute queries directly against a datacontext if you're using entity framework. Just make sure if you're doing anything with parameters you're parameterizing the query and not taking user input directly into it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx

Comment: my column is not an integer its a string and i need to cut of FA- or EHO- from 00001 then check max...and return only number for example 59. does my explanation make any sense? thanks

Comment: I see, are you using EF? If so you can execute queries like the one you have above directly against the data context. I've edited my answer with a second link that will show you what I mean.

Comment: ahh i have no experience with that particular tool. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var list = DBContext.EHO_Action
                    .Where(x => x.YourListColumn != null)
                    .Select(x => x.YourListColumn).ToList(); // Take the list (FA-00001 ,FA-00059) from db to a list

var maxNo = list.Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('-')[1]));
```

Please change the context and column names according to your Linq context.

If you want to use sql you can do it this way..

```
var list = DBContext.ExecuteQuery<string>("select yourreqrdcolumn from [ClientRC].[dbo].[EHO_Action]");
```

Comment: i had just thought same solution but thought it wont be optimized would not it be better to take max number from sql directly?

Comment: Yes, that sounds a good idea but only if you are working directly on something that is directly in int or similar datatype in your sql. But if you want to do string manipulation directly like converting or parsing a string using linq-tosql will give you format conversion errors. So, I have taken it to a list , and used dot net string manipulation on it.. Its totally your preference.

Comment: thanks it is working but when column is null it gives exception any idea?
and how can we run this same sql query from DBContext.Executequery to get scalar value without sending paramter?

Comment: What do you mean by "without sending parameter?"

Comment: the second parameter to DBCOntext.ExecuteQuery is Parameter [] array but i just want to run above sql and get max number. your solution works perfectly but for future if i have sql i want to get scalar...

Comment: see edited answer, is that what you are looking for.. please correct me if I was wrong..

Comment: But if you decided to use linq-to-sql, please stick to retrieving data using linq itself, as its strongly typed and most of the times compile to best sql query available, instead of using own queries.

Comment: hmm thanks i cannot see any executequery with a single parameter all i have is
public IEnumerable ExecuteQuery(Type elementType, string query, params object[] parameters);
public IEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteQuery<TResult>(string query, params object[] parameters);
is it because i am using CodeSmith?

Comment: it is still giving Exception "Sequence contains no elements". i think if there should not be any element it should convert it to 0 (zero). any idea? PS: i solved it by doing if(list.count == 0) return 0 else return list.Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('-')[1])); better?

Comment: oh no.. I understand now what you mean, you want to return a single value from your sql directly, The only way I can think of is to make your working sql query to run in a stored proc and use it in your code directly. `DBContext.YourStoredProc(/* parameters if any */)`

Comment: that sucks that you cannot run direct sql command :P thanks anyway.